# How do Rails Ajax Helpers Work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

In Rails 3, suppose I have the following code:

**Controller**

```
...
format.js # create.js.erb
...
```

**create.js.erb**

```
$('#element').html("new content");
```

**View form**

```
...
button_to 'Create', element, remote: true
```

I wonder how the JS in the `create.js.erb` file gets called.
My guess is that it returns JS code, and some Rails helpers invoke it when it's received. Is this correct, or is there any other kind of magic going on here?

Comment: It depends on how client sends the request. Controller renders the view based on the HTML/JS/XML request accordingly. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds/ClassMethods.html#method-i-respond_to

Comment: I'm interested in the JS part as you can see from my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

**Short answer**: Basically, your assumption is correct, it will return the JS code which will then be executed.

**Slightly longer answer**: There is some magic behind it, though.
When the button is clicked, it will fire a JSON request to the create url, but asking for the format 'js' instead.

The controller then knows that the format expected is 'js' and, after running the `create` action, will render the template for that format -- `create.js.erb`.

Rails knows that it should do this custom JSON request because of the `:remote => true` option. It adds a `data-remote=true` attribute to the link element.

Then, a handler specified in `rails.js` ([link](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js)) is attached to every element with this data-attribute, which takes care of the rest.

**Original Answer below**

Rails uses a technique called **Unobtrusive Javascript** to attach the handlers you specify on .js files to their respective events.

You can read more about it on [this](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/06/unobtrusive-javascript-in-rails-3/) (more specifically part 3) and [this](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/06/unobtrusive-javascript-technique/) article.

**Or**, you could take the most fun route and take a look at the `rails.js` file to see how all the magic works :)

Comment: Right. I edited the answer to be a little more clear. Is that more to your liking?